# Can't find the bug/probleem in my program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm making my first project c++. It's a simple temperature converter.

I made a test section [code 1] with if statements. the if statement would compare the user input. for example if you user typed c and then k(Celsius-Kelvin). it should run the function[code 2] CtoK(); but i doesn't it runs all function why does it do this?

It try to use return but i didn't(it also didn't gave a error so i kept it)

If you guys see something else pls say it [Code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5sGZVKhu)

Also thinks to keep it mind:
Just stated to learn C++
Not native English so if there are spelling and grammar mistakes please say it so i can learn form it

[code 1]

```
void whatToWhat(char firstDegrees, char secondDegrees) {
    if (firstDegrees == 'C' || 'c') {// tests if the user want form c to f
        if (secondDegrees == 'F' || 'f') {
            CtoF();
        }
    }if (firstDegrees == 'C' || 'c') {// tests if the user want form c to k
        if (secondDegrees == 'K' || 'k') {
            CtoK();
        }
    }if (firstDegrees == 'F' || 'f') {// tests if the user want form f to c
        if (secondDegrees == 'C' || 'c') {
            FtoC();
        } 
    }if (firstDegrees == 'F' || 'f') {// tests if the user want form f to k
        if (secondDegrees == 'K' || 'k') {
            FtoK();
        }
    }if (firstDegrees == 'K' || 'k') {// tests if the user want form k to f
        if (secondDegrees == 'F' || 'f') {
            KtoF();
        }
    }if (firstDegrees == 'K' || 'k') {// tests if the user want form k to c
        if (secondDegrees == 'C' || 'c') {
            KtoC();
        }
    }
}
```

[code 2]

```
 void CtoF() {// c to f furmula
    double input;
    cout << "Enter a number[Celsius-Fahrenheit]" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << "it's " << input * 1.8 + 32 << " Fahrenheit " << endl;
    return;
}
void CtoK() {// c to k  furmula
    double input;
    cout << "Enter a number[Celsius-Kelvin]" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << "it's " << input + 273.15   << " Kelvin " << endl;
    return;
}
void FtoC() {//f to c furmula
    double input;
    cout << "Enter a number[Fahrenheit-Celsius]" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << "it's " << input / 1.8 - 32 << " Celsius " << endl;

}
void FtoK() {//f to k furmula
    double input;
    cout << "Enter a number[Fahrenheit-Kelvin]" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << "it's " << input / 1.8 - 32 + 273.15 << " Kelvin " << endl;
    return;
}
void KtoF() {// k to f furmula
    double input;
    cout << "Enter a number[Kelvin-Fahrenheit]" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << "it's " << (input - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32 << " Fahrenheit " << endl;

}
void KtoC() {// k to c furmula
    double input;
    cout << "Enter a number[Kelvin-Celsius]" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cout << "it's " <<273.15 - input << " Celsius " << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: `firstDegrees == 'C' || 'c'` - the comparison is not working like this... Probably you want `firstDegrees == 'C' || firstDegrees  == 'c'`

Comment: 1) if you have more than 1 related `if` you should have `else if` and `else`.
2) `if (firstDegrees == 'C' || 'c')` I believe always evaluates to true

Comment: I've seen this mistake many times in Python, but this is a first for C++.

Comment: @MarkRansom Believe it or not it's common mistake in c++ as well.

Comment: Alas, finding one of the probably *hundreds* of duplicates of this is near and futile exercise in efficiency, as the question titles and text are usually so nebulous there's almost no common thread to latch on to. A reference to a language primer is a decent fallback, I suppose.

Comment: The '||' operator doesn't work quite like you seem to think it does..

Comment: why does it read the function one by one if i'm just calling one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(firstDegrees == 'K' || 'k')` will always evaluate to **true** since `k` **as it is** is `Not Null`, means *Valid*, means *True*.

You need to write all your expressions in a similar way to this: `(firstDegrees == 'K' || firstDegrees == 'k')`

Also, you would want to add `else`s after each `if`, for better and clearer logic control.

Comment: 'k' cannot be `null` as it is not a pointer. For better and clearer logic control `swith` would be better IMHO.

Comment: `if(null)` will evaluate to false. That is what I meant with `Not Null`. To clarify more I added other terms like `Valid` and `True`

Comment: there is no such thing as `null` and `if(null)` is a syntax error. And `if()` cannot evaluate to `false`. 0 will evalute to false, '\0' will as well, `nullptr` will evaluate to false. You should be clearer what you mean by `Null`

Comment: Yup you are right. `if(NULL)` is not the syntax error but `if(null)` is